# Bootstrap displaying a div element in whole window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make a `iframe` element to fill the whole remaining window down to it in bootstrap. My code was like this

#### HTML

```
<div id="mcontainer" class="container-fluid">
  <div id="BMShid" class="hidden">
    <iframe class="col-xs-12" id="BMSfrm" >
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#mcontainer{
  height:100%; 
  width:100%
}
#BMSfrm{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what specific problems did you encounter? Please read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: It's <div class="row">
<iframe class="col-xs-12" ></iframe></div>
I tried span and gave hwight and width = 100% but not working

Comment: Thanks for the edit - not my area of expertise, but you're much more likely to find someone willing to answer now :-)

Answer (score 0):

The old trick is to set `height:100%` to the html and body element. The problem is that for them to get 100% height they need their parents to have 100% height. If one of the iframe's parents is not 100% tall the iframe won't be able to go beyond that parent's height, and this include the `body` and `html` elements. Also, set `display:block` to the `iframe`

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
#mcontainer{
  height:100%; 
  width:100%;
}
#BMSfrm{
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tom! I used absolute positioning which has also solved the problem

Comment: @WtoWpioneers: You should add it as a response and mark it as the answer then :)